# sorting html table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in html, I have set for each td an id that I will need to sort the table with a Jquery code.

Sorting works with the FireFox browser, but with Chrome it does not work ... do you know how to help me?

```js
$(function() {

  $(".table-user-th").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $('.table-user-th').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
    $(this).addClass(o);

    var colIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
    var tbod = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
    var rows = tbod.find("tr");

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).attr('id');;
      var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).attr('id');;

      if (!isNaN(A)) A = Number(A);
      if (!isNaN(B)) B = Number(B);

      return o == 'asc' ? A > B : B > A;
    });

    $.each(rows, function(index, ele) {
      tbod.append(ele);
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-user-th">Firstname</th>
      <th class="table-user-th">Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="Mark">Mark</td>
      <td id="Red">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Nick">Nick</td>
      <td id="Sid">Sid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Alex">Alex</td>
      <td id="Nirv">Nirv</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21927573) then create a `[<>]` snippet with reelevant HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no purpose of using ids here.

Actually the problem was in you sort function. It should return not just true/false but the numeric difference between two values. As usual it is return -1/0/1

So here I wrote comparator func that does just that. And depending on sort type I just multiply it on -1 or 1.

I've also refactored a little bit your code not to use classes or ids. Using jquery you can use `data` method that stores data on element by key/value.

```js
$(function() {
  function cmp(a,b) {return a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0}

  $(".sortable-table").on('click', 'th', function() {
    var th = $(this);
    var colIndex = th.data('column');
    if(typeof colIndex === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
    var sortType = th.data('sort') === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    th.data('sort', sortType);
    var table = $(this).closest("table");
    table.find('thead th').removeClass('asc desc');
    th.addClass(sortType);

    var tbody = table.find("tbody");
    var rows = tbody.find("tr");

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();
      var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();
      return cmp(A,B) * (sortType === 'asc' ? -1 : 1);
    });

    $.each(rows, function(index, ele) {
      tbody.append(ele);
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="sortable-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="0">Firstname</th>
      <th data-column="1">Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nick</td>
      <td>Sid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>Nirv</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update**

Added

```
        var table = $(this).closest("table");
        table.find('thead th').removeClass('asc desc');
        th.addClass(sortType);
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, I saw your code but I see that it does not add to the class of the <th> asc or desc

Comment: @stefanoirves, yes, I've mentioned it. If you need it for css then you can add it. Updating...